# Get the contents(full of text) from the paragraph beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the contents (full of text) of a paragraph from a news webpages, I have a set of url's from which it should extract only the content of a paragraphs. When i use the code below it gives me whole html page.
Here is my code

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
p = opener.open("http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/09/world/europe/turkey-is-courted-by-us-to-help-         fight-isis.html?module=Search&mabReward=relbias%3Aw%2C%7B%222%22%3A%22RI%3A18%22%7D&_r=0")
print p.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(p)
content = soup.find('p', attrs= {'class' : 'story-body-text story-content'})
print content
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are having `print p.read()` line that prints out the whole HTML page.

To get the article text, find it by `id` and then all paragraphs inside the article.

Example using [`CSS Selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(p)
print ''.join(p.text for p in soup.select('article#story p.story-content'))
```

Prints:

```
ANKARA, Turkey —  The Obama administration on Monday began the work of trying to determine
...
```

FYI, `article#story p.story-content` would match all `p` tags that have `story-content` class inside the `article` tag with `story` id.

Comment: p.text.encode('utf-8') if it doesn't print well in your IDE.