# Extract News article content from stored .html pages

Tags: python, urllib2, beautifulsoup

I am reading text from html files and doing some analysis. These .html files are news articles.

**Code:**

```
 html = open(filepath,'r').read()
 raw = nltk.clean_html(html)  
 raw.unidecode(item.decode('utf8'))
```

Now I just want the article content and not the rest of the text like advertisements, headings etc. How can I do so relatively accurately in python?

I know some tools like Jsoup(a java api) and [bolier](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/downloads/list) but I want to do so in python. I could find some techniques using [bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752027/get-the-contentsfull-of-text-from-the-paragraph-beautiful-soup) but there limited to one type of page. And I have news pages from numerous sources. Also, there is dearth of any sample code example present.

I am looking for something exactly like this http://www.psl.cs.columbia.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/3463-WWWJ.pdf in python.

**EDIT:**
To better understand, please write a sample code to extract the content of the following link http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/19/health/study-finds-dense-breast-tissue-isnt-always-a-high-cancer-risk.html?src=me&ref=general

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are libraries for this in Python too :)

Since you mentioned Java, there's a Python wrapper for boilerpipe that allows you to directly use it inside a python script: https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe

If you want to use purely python libraries, there are 2 options:

https://github.com/buriy/python-readability

and

https://github.com/grangier/python-goose

Of the two, I prefer Goose, however be aware that the recent versions of it sometimes fail to extract text for some reason (my recommendation is to use version 1.0.22 for now)

EDIT: here's a sample code using Goose:

```
from goose import Goose
from requests import get

response = get('http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/19/health/study-finds-dense-breast-tissue-isnt-always-a-high-cancer-risk.html?src=me&ref=general')
extractor = Goose()
article = extractor.extract(raw_html=response.content)
text = article.cleaned_text
```

Comment: This is really nice to know library, which also uses NLTK. For those who want to install, on PyPi it goes as goose-extractor, because Goose is for another, unrelated tool .

Comment: Can you check the code you provided above. It doesn't seem to work. text is empty.

Comment: use version 1.0.22 of goose. As i've said, the new versions have some annoying bugs that prevent them from extracting some content, NYTimes being one of them :(

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. But at times I get an error : IOError: Couldn't open file C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\goose_extractor-1.0.22-py2.7.egg\goose\resources\text\stopwords-ut.txt . I couldn't find any reference to it online. Can you please help.

Comment: this is another annoying bug of Goose. They fixed in in recent versions, but those are the versions that couldn't extract from NYTimes :( I've a fork of python-goose that do both, which you can access at https://github.com/agolo/python-goose/

Comment: actually, use this fork instead: it's a more up-to-date version than mine https://github.com/robmcdan/python-goose

Comment: I haven't used git much. Just to clarify I should reinstall Goose using this now instead `git clone https://github.com/robmcdan/python-goose`?

Comment: uninstall your current Goose, and then do this in the terminal:
`pip install git+git://github.com/robmcdan/python-goose.git`

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.9 and have tried it times `git clone https://github.com/agolo/python-goose` but the above code doesn't work. It doesn't print anything `print text.encode('ascii','ignore')`. Can you please check.

Comment: try the new code, which use `requests` to fetch the html instead of relying on Goose's internal function

Comment: Thanks again! Please check it doesn't work for this http://tribune.com.pk/story/773657/pti-multan-administration-trade-blame-after-8-people-killed-in-qasim-bagh-stampede/

Comment: Oh sorry! It was mistaken. There is a one minute the text I get is devoided of any " ". As you will notice in the above link. In my case, I especially I want to use such text. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: i don't really get what you are saying. the output that i get looks fine.

Comment: I wanted to ask you about the encoding of the final text. Do I need perform some preprocessing on it?

Comment: It seems at times I have use .encode('ascii','ignore') but this removes " " in the text sometimes.

Comment: this is a whole other discussion re: how to handle unicode in python 2, which is not the scope of this thread. I suggest you read up on that first (a good resource is http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), and make new questions if you still can't make it work.

Comment: and yes, some of the spaces in the output (which is unicode) are non-breaking space characters, which will get removed if you use `.encode('ascii','ignore')`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78365/discussion-on-answer-by-oxymor0n-extract-news-article-content-from-stored-html).

Comment: @oxymor0n Can you please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381944/read-article-content-using-goose-retrieving-nothing

Answer (score 17):

[Newspaper](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper) is becoming increasingly popular, I've only used it superficially, but it looks good. It's Python 3 only.

The quickstart only shows loading from a URL, but you can [load from a HTML string](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/291) with:

```
import newspaper

# LOAD HTML INTO STRING FROM FILE...

article = newspaper.Article('') # STRING REQUIRED AS `url` ARGUMENT BUT NOT USED
article.set_html(html)
```

Comment: This is a good approach but note that you have to provide a URL to Article() so better to use `Article(url='http://example.com/test-url')`. The article won't need to be downloaded as you then use `article.set_html(html)` to set the html locally.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the API has changed since I wrote this and requires a URL string as a positional argument, it's come up in this issue https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/291. You can instantiate with a blank string (`article = newspaper.Article('')`) without any problems, that may be clearer than setting a real URL if it won't be downloaded and parsed.

Comment: @AlanBuxton I have tried that,  but im getting the error when i try to parse it (article.parse()), and if i do not parse it I can not extract text and title from article. How can I override that?

Comment: @AlanBuxton, how did you solve above issue ? please

Comment: Hi @tursunWali I have always found that newspaper works very well. Can you give some more info on the issue you are having?

Comment: Alan Buxton, I meant this "I have tried that, but im getting the error when i try to parse it (article.parse()), and if i do not parse it I can not extract text and title from article. How can I override that? – taga ". I am using newsletter3k, works with Python3. I want to work with news text I stored locally. How to do it, I wonder.

Comment: @tursunWali `input_html` argument of `download` method could help in your case ... Example (`body` is the html content as a string): `article = Article("https://www.example.com"); article.download(input_html=body); article.parse()` This is the code where you see how `input_html` is processed: https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/article.py#L189-L200

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this by visiting the page directly:

```
##Import modules
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


##Grab the page
url = http://www.example.com
req = urllib2.Request(url)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = page.read()
page.close()  

##Prepare
soup = BeautifulSoup(content) 

##Parse (a table, for example)

for link in soup.find_all("table",{"class":"myClass"}):
    ...do something...
pass
```

If you want to load a file, just replace the part where you grab the page with the file instead. Find out more here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to organize html-scaraping in Python. As said in other answers, the tool #1 is BeautifulSoup, but there are others:

- http://scrapy.org/
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/)
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

Here are useful resources:

- http://www.gregreda.com/2013/03/03/web-scraping-101-with-python/
- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

There is no universal way of finding the content of the article. HTML5 has article tag, hinting on the main text, and it is maybe possible to tune scraping for pages from specific publishing systems, but there is no general way to get the accurately guess text location. (Theoretically, machine can deduce page structure from looking at more than one structurally identical, different in content articles, but this is probably out of scope here.)

Also [Web scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python) may be relevant.

Pyquery example for NYT:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
url = 'http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/19/health/study-finds-dense-breast-tissue-isnt-always-a-high-cancer-risk.html?src=me&ref=general'
d = pq(url=url)
text = d('.story-content').text()
```

Comment: What about packages like the one @oxymor0n? What do you tjink about their accuracy

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia the answer and goose-extractor was new to me, so it may work and seems to be nearest to your specs, but hard to say without testing. I guess, his answer is the best one here. Please, accept it if nothing better comes.

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend using [Trafilatura](https://github.com/adbar/trafilatura). Super easy to implement and it's fast!

```
import trafilatura
url = 'www.example.com'
downloaded = trafilatura.fetch_url(url)
article_content = trafilatura.extract(downloaded)
```

Which gives:

```
'This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\ndomain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.\nMore information...'
```

You can also give it the HTML directly, like this:

```
trafilatura_text = trafilatura.extract(html, include_comments=False)
```

If you're interested in more fields, like authors / publication date, you can use bare_extraction:

```
import trafilatura
url = 'www.example.com'
downloaded = trafilatura.fetch_url(url)
trafilatura.bare_extraction(downloaded, include_links=True)
```

Which will give you:

```
{'title': 'Example Domain',
 'author': None,
 'url': None,
 'hostname': None,
 'description': None,
 'sitename': None,
 'date': None,
 'categories': [],
 'tags': [],
 'fingerprint': None,
 'id': None,
 'license': None,
 'body': None,
 'comments': '',
 'commentsbody': None,
 'raw_text': None,
 'text': 'This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\ndomain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.\nMore information...'}
```

Comment: your answer is the only one that works, all the other fancy tools like scrapy or whatever just don't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [htmllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html) or [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) you can use these to parse your html file

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

A sample of code tooken from HTMLParser page