# Accessing JVM from python

Tags: java, python, jvm, boilerpipe

```
>>> import boilerpipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boilerpipe\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % os.pathsep.join(jars))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 50, in startJVM
    _jpype.startup(jvm, tuple(args), True)
RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll], error = The specified module could not be found.
 at native\common\include\jp_platform_win32.h:58
```

Tried: 
Reinstalling jvm

```
>> import ctypes
>> import os
>> os.chdir(r"<path to Java bin client folder>")
>> ctypes.CDLL("jvm.dll")
Still unable to fix
```

Edit:
Tried code below, still stuck:

`from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway 
gateway = JavaGateway()`
It gives the same error as before.

Comment: Loading the JVM from a DLL is very hard even from C.  I suggest you load the JVM using `java` from the command line or use Jython which runs in the JVM already.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for comment! I am unaware of `Jython`. Should I just install it and run my python script again? Or there is more to it?

Comment: Jython runs Python scripts inside the JVM. I assume there is more to it but this is designed and supported to work with the JVM it is running in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python

Comment: @ρss I am very new using java in python. How can this solve my issue? I just want to simply use this package.

Comment: @ρss Tried this. `>>> from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
>>> gateway = JavaGateway()  ` Still the same error.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Please update your question with the new tests that you have made, instead of mentioning them in a comment.

Comment: @ρss Okay done, please check and help if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would like to also recommend trying Jython. From Jython you can access everything in Java. What Jython is, is that you run Python *inside* Java and so direct access to everything inside Java.

Comment: Also  you don't say what the problem is with the last example.

Comment: @Prof.Falken I don't want to install another python distribution. Is it possible to install `Jython` to already present python version. If that makes some sense.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, no, not exactly. You install it to already present *Java* installation. Or you just include the Jython **jar** file inside your Java project. Then nothing at all needs to be installed. http://www.jython.org/downloads.html

Comment: @Prof.Falken Sorry I don't exactly understand. Please explain `Jython jar file inside your Java project`. Are you talking about the boilerpipe library here or my script which uses boilerpipe.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, I am saying that you if you had Jython, you could import any Java library.

Comment: The problem with jython is that a lot of python stuff doesn't work with it (a lot of the more advanced modules out there use C extensions). I've had good initial success with [jpype](https://github.com/originell/jpype), though I haven't used it super extensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Please !

1. Give a true path (`"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\client\\jvm.dll"`)
2. Check all 32 or 64 bit (my offer always use 32bit Anaconda,JRE7,Python etc.)
3. Install pywin32 (of course python2.7.9)
4. Give permission to `jvm.dll`(can run)
5. After all is ok, try: `import ctypes` `ctypes.CDLL('C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll')`

***Maybe can't throw the hook of some java versions
   i used `jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe`

i hope helpful ! Best regards !

Works on wine(no bug):
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I get this error unforunately. `>>> ctypes.CDLL('C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\client\jvm.dll')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found`

Comment: How does one give permission to the dll to "can run"? We are searching the web but the keywords are so generic we are not finding good answers.

Comment: Depends on the operating system version. Some application extensions only require access (sometimes the right to access and/or user and/or user group and/or access class and/or service point etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Answering because I don't have enough rep for commenting; Try using raw strings instead of the normal ones allowing "\x" escapes. Try:

```
>>> ctypes.CDLL(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\client\jvm.dll')
```

Because the "\..." parts of the string could very well be escapes.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are not sufficient, one also needs to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) as per Bjorns [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226497/difficulties-starting-jvm-in-python-using-jpype).

After installed the C++ redistributable:

1. Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to ("C:\Program Files\Java\jre7")
2. Use paths as mentioned above to start jvm:

   path_to_jvm = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll"

   jpype.startJVM(path_to_jvm)

   jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access JVM on Windows operation system, make sure you have the right version of JVM (32-bit or 64-bit) installed. In my case python was 64-bit and once I installed Java 64-bit, it worked without needing to specify the path or any other extra requirements.