# How to grant permission to a DLL to run on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: java, python, windows-server-2016

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045648/accessing-jvm-from-python) specifies that the Java DLL jvm.dll needs to be given "can run" privileges for Python to call a ctypes command on it (i.e. `ctypes.CDLL(r'<path>/jvm.dll')`)

We are running on Windows Server 2016.

How do we give that type of execution privilege? And to whom or what do we give it?